# formating number on laravel datatable

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatables

I use datatable on laravel, and I want to make a Eloquent Query.
I have a field which is double, I want to show numbers like this :

456878   -> 456 878.00

456878.5 -> 456 878.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can edit each line of the query's result by editing the specific field like this :

first we make a query :

```
$lists = Command::select([
           'commands.id as id',
           'commands.price as price',
        ]);

$datatables = DataTables::of($lists);
```

second we edit the column :

```
$datatables->editColumn('price', function ($command) {
     return number_format($command->price, 2, '.', ' ');
});
```

finally we return the result :

```
return $datatables->make(true);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.